# Dapper - Get value of output parameter from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper, output-parameter

Without using Dapper, this code returns the correct result of "true":

```cs
using(connection= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText= query;
        cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;

        var pDeviceId = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@DeviceId",
            DbType = DbType.String,
            Size = 150,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = parameter.DeviceId
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pDeviceId);

        var pResponse = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Response",
            DbType = DbType.Boolean,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pResponse);

        await connection.OpenAsync();

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var response = (bool)cmd.Parameters["@Response"].Value;

        return response;
    }
}
```

But when using Dapper, I can't get this code to work. It always returns a value of "false":

```cs
using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@DeviceId", parameter.DeviceId);
        parameters.Add("@Response", dbType: DbType.Boolean, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

        var reply = (await connection.QueryAsync<bool>(
            query,
            param: parameters,
            commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(false)).FirstOrDefault();
        return reply;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Stored Proc that you used?

Comment: Hi @Ibanez, I think you should use `ExecuteAsync` instead of `QueryAsync` as you just want the value from the output parameter, but don't need the result from the SELECT statement. Check out my latest answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add your solution to your question. If the answer you have accepted doesn't contain a full answer then feel free to add your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here,

```cs
var reply = (await connection.QueryAsync<bool>(
            query,
            param: parameters,
            commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(false)).FirstOrDefault();
```

this will get the value from the `SELECT` statement from the stored procedure, but not the value from the `Output` parameter.

To get the value from the output parameter, you should do as below:

```cs
await connection.ExecuteAsync(
    query,
    param: parameters,
    commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

var reply = parameters.Get<bool>("@Response");
```

**References**

1. [Dapper/ProcedureTest.cs (`TestDateTime2LosePrecisionInDynamicParameters` method)](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/6ec3804f2c44f2bf6b757dc3522bf009cc64b27d/tests/Dapper.Tests/ProcedureTests.cs#L230-L261)
2. [Using Parameters With Dapper (Dapper Output Parameter section)](https://www.learndapper.com/parameters)

Comment: Hmm. What could be the difference?

Comment: Result is same. Just remove the unnecessary code, and use the correct approach.